# tryParse not converting value

Tags: vb.net

I have Option Strict On. The code below does not work when I it is on. I was able to isolate the issue to this line

```
Decimal.TryParse(lblAnnualMid.Text, decAnnualMid)
```

Because this line is not changing the value from text to decimal, the rest of my code does not work and my labels display $0.

How can I fix this. I am still feeling my way through VB.Net so if this seems obvious, please forgive me.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class frmCustomRanges

    'Variables for the MidPoint TextBoxes
    Dim decAnnualMid As Decimal
    Dim decHourlyMid As Decimal

Private Sub txtRangeSpread_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRangeSpread.TextChanged

        'This event runs when the user enters a number in the 
        'txtRangeSpread text box. The amount is converted to a decimal
        'it then calculates the min and max of the range for annual
        'and hourly ranges.  The ranges change as the user changes the range
        'spread.


        'Variables for the event
        Dim decRangeSpreadResults As Decimal

        'Verify entry is numeric
        If IsNumeric(txtRangeSpread.Text) Then

            'Convert entry to decimal
            Dim decRangeSpread As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRangeSpread.Text)

            'convert the Mid point value to decimal
            Decimal.TryParse(lblAnnualMid.Text, decAnnualMid)

            'convert range spread value to percentage
            decRangeSpreadResults = decRangeSpread / 100


            'Display results in dollar string Annual salary
            lblAnnualMin.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(decAnnualMid - (decRangeSpreadResults * decAnnualMid)).ToString("C")
            lblAnnualMax.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(decAnnualMid + (decRangeSpreadResults * decAnnualMid)).ToString("C")

            ''Display results in dollar string in Hourly rate
            lblHourlyMin.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(decAnnualMid + (decRangeSpreadResults * decAnnualMid) / 52 / 40).ToString("C")
            lblHourlyMax.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(decAnnualMid + (decRangeSpreadResults * decAnnualMid) / 52 / 40).ToString("C")

        Else

            MsgBox("You have entered a non-numeric value. Please check value and enter again", vbCritical, "Input Error")


            With txtRangeSpread
                .Text = ""
                .Focus()

            End With

        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: what does your input look lik?

Comment: The input is a 2 digit number ie: 35

Comment: What is in `lblAnnualMid.Text` at the start of your program?  Does it have a default value at start?

Comment: If you have an error TryParse will output 0 to your variable. You need to test that the result of `Decimal.TryParse` is true. Try putting a breakpoint on your TryParse statement to see what the value actually is.

Comment: I suspect that whatever is going on in `ToString("C")` is what's causing the $0 output. What's the output if you just use `ToString()` instead?

Comment: Another possible problem is that `decRangeSpread / 100` returns a value of type `Double` instead of type `Decimal`.

Comment: I think I tracked down the issue. lblAnnualMid contains the output with a $ ie: $35,000. I think this is throwing off the line Decimal.TryParse(lblAnnualMid.Text, decAnnualMid)

Comment: Why are you calling Convert.ToDecimal on variables that are already of type Decimal?  That is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want in fact would be this

```
  decimal.TryParse("$35,000",NumberStyles.Currency ,null , out test)
```

ex:

```
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                decimal test;
                Console.WriteLine(decimal.TryParse("$35,000",NumberStyles.Currency ,null , out test));
                Console.WriteLine(test);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

[more information about NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my line to:

```
Decimal.TryParse(lblAnnualMid.Text.Replace("$", ""), decAnnualMid)
```

this worked perfect.

thank you all.

Comment: You should be checking the return value with `if Decimal.TryParse()` so your code can tell if it worked or not and decide how to proceed.

Comment: @KenWhite: Try parse returns the default value if it fails, and sometimes that is what you want.  But you're right, that doesn't seem to be what is desired tha time and the IsNumeric should probably be replaced with a tryparse.

Comment: @jmoreno - TryParse returns a boolean indicating whether or not the parsing succeeded.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Ok, it **assigns** the default value if it fails.